# Overlap issue on Arabic characters

Tags: html, arabic

For example

```
<textarea dir="auto">#عَرَبِيّ</textarea>
```

It will display overlap char with symbol #. How can I deal it?[image]

Comment: Please provide some code. css would help.

Answer (score 0):

That's Arabic for you.  It's tricky to use in any language.

For this issue you could simply add a space in between the hashtag and the Arabic text, making them not overlap each other.  Or if what you want is for the hashtag to be over the Arabic text then the CSS `z-index` element would work well.

```css
#hashtag {
  z-index: 1;
}

#arabic {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a id="hashtag">
  #
</a>
<a id="arabic">
  عَرَبِيّ
</a>
```

[More on z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: It is for an editor project for multiple language support (especially Arabic language), so I can't just simply add html inside textarea. I found the problem is actually cause by dir="auto" but since we need support Arabic character this setting is actually required. I'm looking for some work around solutions.